Can I use any kind of wheat dextrin in place of Evercrisp?
I've recently come to learn of Evercrisp, which is supposed to keep food crispy for long periods of time. However I can't really seem to be able to find it where I live. On the ingredients, it says it's just wheat dextrin, which I should be able to find on Amazon.
Is it worth trying to buy wheat dextrin that's branded as a fiber supplement? Or are there any other substitutes that would work just as good? I love fried foods and I'd love to be able to carry them to work in a lunchbox but I'm tired of them getting all soggy by lunchtime.
